# UIPickerView iOS7 Touch Row To Select

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uipickerview

iOS7 has changed the UIPickerView, it only returns 3 subviews now, and the second subview has some of its own subviews.

I've been trying to add a UIGestureRecogniser to each of the subviews to allow the center row to be touch selected, but no luck.

Even adding a UIView to the UIPickerView does nothing, it doesn't respond to any touches.

What the hell do I do?!?

Comment: Relying on a specific configuration for the internals of one of Apple's components is a bad idea (and as you have discovered, fragile, unsupported, and likely to break with new OS versions). I'm not quite sure what your specific use case is, but if you really need to do something like this you should be building your own picker view or using a third party component which can be easily modified.